# PyObject_CallMethod return -1

Tags: python, c++

I use c++ to control python 2.7, but calling the method does not return the correct value to me. Moreover, instead of argument 5, the method gets 1 - why is this so?

```
PyObject * ws = PyImport_ImportModule("cppMethods"); //cppMethods.py
PyObject* klass = PyObject_GetAttrString(ws, "cppMethods"); //class
PyObject* instance = PyInstance_New(klass, NULL, NULL);
//call_method<int>(instance, "getSum", 1);
PyObject* result = PyObject_CallMethod(instance, "getSum", "i", 5);
auto res3 = PyInt_AsLong(result); //-1 here
```

> 

```
class cppMethods():

    def getSum(self, a):
        print("This line will be printed.");
        print("a=",a);
        number = a + 3;
        print("number=",number);
        return number;
```

Comment: Why are you going through `std::string` and `new char[]` and `strcpy` just to get C strings?

Comment: And why does your format string have *two* `i`s?

Comment: 1. get C strings - I did not know another method. I am newbie.
2. two i - yes it was mistakenly left. I removed it in the code but the result did not change (

Comment: You should not have any superfluous stuff left after you created a [mcve]. That's why it's required and why your question is off-topic without one. BTW: If you ever use `new []` in C++, you are most likely doing something wrong. Even for temporary arrays, use `std::vector`.

Comment: Ok I just simplified the code of the example. help now solve the problem.

Comment: Again, provide a MCVE. Your question is off-topic as it stands due to the lack of one and there are good reasons why that is considered off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how it all worked:

```
object module = import("cppMethods");
object _class = module.attr("cppMethods")();
auto res = _class.attr("getSum")(5);
int x = extract<int>(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

The format string used for `PyObject_CallMethod` should produce a tuple. [You need to parenthesize the string contents](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/arg.html#c.Py_BuildValue) to force a tuple when there's only one value:

```
PyObject_CallMethod(instance, "getSum", "(i)", 5)
```

Comment: Yes, I tried so "(i)" now checked again, did not help ( Where that took the example of Py_BuildValue() also did not work. maybe I did not use it correctly I do not know